# How to get double quoted value with out \ from the database in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I am fetching some string value from the database which should have double quotes, for example:

```
"DoubleQuotes"
```

but when ever it comes to the c# part above string value becomes:

```
\"DoubleQuotes\"
```

I have even tried using replace method but it takes out the `\` but also removes `"` from everywhere.

Code:

```
repository = new Repository();
string genericTemplate = Convert.ToString(@repository.GetTemplateWithoutFormulas(sheetName)); // this returns the string value from the db
return genericTemplate;
```

O/p on the browser I get is:

```
"{\"version\":\"9.40.20153.0\",\"sheetCount\":2,\"sheets\":{\"Sheet1\":{\"name\":\"Sheet1\",\"selections\":{\"0\":{\"row\":1,\"rowCount\":1,\"col\":1,\"colCount\":1}},\"rowCount\":200,\"columnCount\":20,\"activeRow\":1,\"activeCol\":1,\"theme\":\"Office\",\"rowHeaderData\":{\"defaultDataNode\":{\"style\":{\"themeFont\":\"Body\"}}},\"colHeaderData\":{\"defaultDataNode\":{\"style\":{\"themeFont\":\"Body\"}}},\"data\":{\"dataTable\":{\"0\":{\"0\":{\"value\":\"daman\",\"style\":{\"autoFormatter\":{\"customerCultureName\":\"en-US\"}}},\"1\":{\"value\":\"sandhu\",\"style\":{\"autoFormatter\":{\"customerCultureName\":\"en-US\"}}}},\"1\":{\"0\":{\"value\":\"hello\",\"style\":{\"autoFormatter\":{\"customerCultureName\":\"en-US\"}}},\"1\":{\"value\":\"chu\",\"style\":{\"autoFormatter\":{\"customerCultureName\":\"en-US\"}}}}},\"defaultDataNode\":{\"style\":{\"themeFont\":\"Body\"}}},\"index\":0},\"Sheet2\":{\"name\":\"Sheet2\",\"selections\":{\"0\":{\"row\":0,\"rowCount\":1,\"col\":0,\"colCount\":1}},\"rowCount\":200,\"columnCount\":20,\"activeRow\":0,\"activeCol\":0,\"theme\":\"Office\",\"index\":1}}}"
```

Comment: Show me a piece of your code.

Comment: It is escaped as it should be.

Comment: tricky question. How do you know it is returning `\"`? ;)

Comment: Updated above with the code

Comment: @Farhan: Agreed, how to overcome from this?

Comment: OHKZ, I have replaced text. Now you can solve it ?

Comment: Actually `\"` represents double quote in a string. If you have to display the text having double quotes then you don't have to worry about back slash.

Answer (score 5):

Your `GetTemplateWithoutFormulas()` method doesn't just return a string, it returns a JSON string of a JSON object. Apparently you stringified one too many times.  You need to parse out that JSON string and get the string representation of that result.

I don't know what libraries you're using but assuming Json.NET, you could do something like this:

```
var template = repository.GetTemplateWithoutFormulas(sheetName);
var token = JToken.Parse(template);
return token.ToString();
```

You should also consider making that method return a JSON object instead, rather than a JSON string of a JSON object. Then you wouldn't have to do this in the first place.